# eclipse and Java ME, "you must add at least one configuration"

Tags: java-me

I need to make an app for my cheap phone, and I downloaded eclipse, java sdk, and java me sdk for it. I can't create a simple Java ME project, because when I click `File`->`New`->`Java ME Project` and type name, it says

```
you must add at least one configuration
```

Tutorial like this http://www.wideskills.com/j2me/configure-java-me-in-eclipse says to go to `Window`->`Preferences`->`Java ME`->`Device Management`->`Manual Install` and provide the path to the Java ME sdk, `C:\Program Files\Java_ME_platform_SDK_8.3` in my case. Except it finds nothing for me.

Comment: Use an older SDK version. My take is the WTK 2.5.2_01 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html

Comment: This worked. Thank you. *bows*

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit and give its path to download! It worked for me. Or add the MTJ (Mobile Tools for Java) plugin and we will have an environment ready to create Java ME applications.
To do this, go to the menu Help > Install new software and add the URL: http://download.eclipse.org/mtj/updates/1.1.2/stable